# Error 404, is my project not actually on localhost or is my path wrong?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest

I am trying to create my first rest API using this simple tutorial h[ttps://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) and cannot seem to find it online. First off, it installs through mvn clean install successfully and then when I run on server with tomcat it opens browser to http://localhost:8080/rest-service/ but returns Status 404. I have tried messing with the URL to give different end points but it is unsuccessful. I cloned from "git clone [https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service.git"](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service.git%22)

Tried:
http://localhost:8080/rest-service/greeting
http://localhost:8080/rest-service/greeting?name=test
http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=test
http://localhost:8080/gs-rest-service/greeting
http://localhost:8080/gs-rest-service/greeting?name=test

The tutorial states: "When you finish, you can check your results against the code in gs-rest-service/complete" my project does not contain a complete folder.
The pom.xml:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>rest-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
```

The tomcat server is online and running because other applications are hosted on it and I can successfully find them on a browser. However, the server.xml file states port # is 8089 meanwhile I navigate to http://localhost:8080/project_name to find other projects.

Greating controller exists as so:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE WITH LOG**

```
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.43
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jan 28 2021 20:25:45 UTC
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.43.0
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Users\AHorner\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.2.v20210201-0955\jre
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           15.0.2+7-27
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\AHorner\eclipse-workspace\eclipse-workspace-ee\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.43
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\AHorner\eclipse-workspace\eclipse-workspace-ee\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.43
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\AHorner\eclipse-workspace\eclipse-workspace-ee\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.26] using APR version [1.7.0].
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020]
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [1057] milliseconds
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.43]
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:45 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:45 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:47 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:47 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:48 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:48 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 03, 2021 4:20:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [3576] milliseconds
```

Comment: How do you start your server/project? Do you launch it from an IDE or from a console? Can you show us some log?

Comment: Share your log.

Comment: @Mannekenpix I run it from Eclipse. Right click, run on server. I added the log od the server startup

Answer (score 0):

You start a Tomcat and not the main Spring Boot class. You should run this class: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service/blob/master/complete/src/main/java/com/example/restservice/RestServiceApplication.java

It is the main Spring Boot class and it will start the embedded Tomcat.

In the guide it is specified:

> The main() method uses Spring Boot’s SpringApplication.run() method to launch an application.